# AWS Step Functions and Fargate task: container runtime error does not cause pipeline to fail

Tags: amazon-web-services, debugging, aws-fargate, aws-step-functions

I have a pipeline defined in [AWS Step Functions](https://aws.amazon.com/it/step-functions/). One step is defined as [Fargate Task](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/AWS_Fargate.html), which pulls a docker image and run some python code. I've surprisingly found that if the container running in the Fargate task encounters a runtime error the Step Functions doesn't catch the failed task and continue the pipeline as normal (setting the Fargate task as successful), but according to [the documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/step-functions/latest/dg/concepts-error-handling.html) the pipeline should fail as soon as this happens.

This is the step function definition:

```json
{
  "Comment": "My state machine",
  "StartAt": "MyFargateTask",
  "States": {
    "MyFargateTask": {
      "Type": "Task",
      "Resource": "arn:aws:states:::ecs:runTask.sync",
      "InputPath": "$",
      "Parameters": {
        "Cluster": "my-cluster",
        "TaskDefinition": "arn:aws:ecs:us-east-1:617090640476:task-definition/my-task:1",
        "LaunchType": "FARGATE",
        "NetworkConfiguration": {
          "AwsvpcConfiguration": {
            "Subnets": [
              "subnet-xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
              "subnet-yyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyy"
            ],
            "AssignPublicIp": "ENABLED"
          }
        },
      },
      "Next": "Done"
    },
    "Done": {
      "Type": "Succeed"
    }
  }
}
```

I've tried the following simple python code for the Fargate container:

```py
def main():
    raise Exception("foobar")

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

In the container logs on CloudWatch I can see the program failing as expected, but the pipeline in the Step Function succeeds (all green).
What am I missing? Is this a bug?

Comment: What is the command for the container? Are you calling that python file explicitly, or do you have a wrapper script?

Comment: CMD python index.py

Comment: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/step-functions/latest/dg/connect-to-resource.html

Answer (score 22, accepted):

AWS Step Functions does not know if an ECS job has succeeded or failed. Step Functions would need to peek into the ECS job's container log, and try to determine if the process running inside the Docker container exited with a failure code. That's not something Step Functions does. As you have it configured, Step Functions simply assumes that whenever the container exists the task has succeeded.

If you change `arn:aws:states:::ecs:runTask.sync` to `arn:aws:states:::ecs:runTask.waitForTaskToken` then instead of just waiting for the ECS container to exit, Step Fuctions will wait for the ECS container to send a success or failure code back to the Step Functions API. You will also need to pass the task token into the ECS container, which can be done with a `ContainerOverrides` setting, like so:

```
{
  "Comment": "My state machine",
  "StartAt": "MyFargateTask",
  "States": {
    "MyFargateTask": {
      "Type": "Task",
      "Resource": "arn:aws:states:::ecs:runTask.waitForTaskToken",
      "InputPath": "$",
      "Parameters": {
        "Cluster": "my-cluster",
        "TaskDefinition": "arn:aws:ecs:us-east-1:617090640476:task-definition/my-task:1",
        "LaunchType": "FARGATE",
        "NetworkConfiguration": {
          "AwsvpcConfiguration": {
            "Subnets": [
              "subnet-xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
              "subnet-yyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyy"
            ],
            "AssignPublicIp": "ENABLED"
          }
        },
        "Overrides": {
          "ContainerOverrides": [{
            "Environment": [{
              "Name": "TASK_TOKEN",
              "Value.$": "$$.Task.Token"
              }]
          }]
        }
      },
      "Next": "Done"
    },
    "Done": {
      "Type": "Succeed"
    }
  }
}
```

Now inside your Python script you can grab the `TASK_TOKEN` environment variable, and issue a success or failure message back to Step Functions like so:

```
token = os.environ['TASK_TOKEN']

def step_success():
    if token is not None:
        stfn = boto3.client('stepfunctions')
        stfn.send_task_success(taskToken=token, output='{"Status": "Success"}')


def step_fail():
    if token is not None:
        stfn = boto3.client('stepfunctions')
        stfn.send_task_failure(taskToken=token, error="An error occurred")
```

[More details on this approach](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/step-functions/latest/dg/connect-to-resource.html#connect-wait-token)

I recommend also configuring a timeout in the state machine in case your Python script fails to execute within the container or something. Also, you will need to add the appropriate IAM permissions to the Fargate task's IAM role to allow it to issues these status calls back to the Step Functions API.

Comment: Thank you very much, I will try this approach!

Answer (score 3):

I think using **arn:aws:states:::ecs:runTask.sync** will make your stepfunction fail, Because ECS will show container status has STOPPED and detail message as " Essential container in task exited"

If you use **arn:aws:states:::ecs:runTask** (without .syn) stepfunction will not bother about ECS and will result in Success.

Given your case, you should use **arn:aws:states:::ecs:runTask.waitForTaskToken** and send sendTaskSuccess or sendTaskFailure with provide token from StepFunction