# Stepfunction timeout does not stop Fargate task

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-fargate, aws-step-functions

I have a step function that orchestrates a combination of lambdas and fargate tasks. This step function has a timeout set to 24 hours. However, this timeout does not propagate to canceling the already running fargate task.

I have looked at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63815158/aws-step-functions-and-fargate-task-container-runtime-error-does-not-cause-pipe) previously to send success and fail messages back to the step function, which works great. I can't figure out how to solve the time out issue though.

Current Config looks like this:

```
    {
    "StartAt": "Fargate-task",
    "States": {
    "Fargate-task": {
        "Next": "pass-state",
        "Catch": [
        {
            "ErrorEquals": [
            "States.ALL"
            ],
            "Next": "fail-state"
        }
        ],
        "Type": "Task",
        "TimeoutSeconds": 60,
        "ResultPath": "$.extractor_output",
        "Resource": "arn:aws:states:::ecs:runTask.waitForTaskToken"
    },
    "pass-state": {
        "Type": "Pass",
        "Next": "Lambda Worker"
    },
    "Lambda Worker": {
        "Type": "Map",
        "End": true,
        "Iterator": {
        "StartAt": "LambdaWorker",
        "States": {
            "LambdaWorker": {
            "End": true,
            "Retry": [
                {
                "ErrorEquals": [
                    "Lambda.ServiceException",
                    "Lambda.AWSLambdaException",
                    "Lambda.SdkClientException"
                ],
                "IntervalSeconds": 2,
                "MaxAttempts": 6,
                "BackoffRate": 2
                }
            ],
            "Type": "Task",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:states:::lambda:invoke",
            "Parameters": {
                "FunctionName": "<LAMBDA>",
                "Payload.$": "$"
            }
            }
        }
        },
        "ItemsPath": "$.extractor_output",
        "MaxConcurrency": 10
    },
    "fail-state": {
        "Type": "Fail"
    }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you please share your step function state machine config?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to handle it would be to catch the timeout error and issue a command to kill the fargate task :

Like in this example from docs https://docs.aws.amazon.com/step-functions/latest/dg/concepts-error-handling.html :

```
{
   "Comment": "A Hello World example of the Amazon States Language using an AWS Lambda function",
   "StartAt": "HelloWorld",
   "States": {
      "HelloWorld": {
         "Type": "Task",
         "Resource": "arn:aws:lambda:us-east-1:123456789012:function:sleep10",
         "TimeoutSeconds": 2,
         "Catch": [ {
            "ErrorEquals": ["States.Timeout"],
            "Next": "fallback"
         } ],
         "End": true
      },
      "fallback": {
         "Type": "Pass",
         "Result": "Hello, AWS Step Functions!",
         "End": true
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: When my config has `States.ALL` shouldn't that give the same result. `States.Timeout` I assume is a subset of `States.All`

Comment: does it matter if I use `waitForTaskToken` instead of `sync`?

Comment: yes States.All also catcj States.Timeout, and yes waitForTaskToken matter, it means that your service must call back step function with a specefic task token. But I don't think you need that sync should be enough for your use case, as stepfunction would attempt to cancel the task for you. Also in your real code you provide parameter with cluster id and job id right ?

Comment: yes, shortened the config for readability. However, when I try aborting the step function manually in the console. The fargate task keep running. My solution now will be to implement a heart beat functionality.

Comment: It also keep running when you use sync ?

Comment: According to documentation I don't seem to be able to put `sync`.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/latest/python/aws_cdk.aws_stepfunctions_tasks/EcsRunTask.html
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/latest/python/aws_cdk.aws_stepfunctions/IntegrationPattern.html#aws_cdk.aws_stepfunctions.IntegrationPattern

Comment: My misstake, `.sync` is represnted by: `RUN_JOB`. I tried `RUN_JOB` instead of `WAIT_FOR_TASK_TOKEN ` and now it works!

Comment: How do you "issue a command to kill the fargate"